# Meteor using variable from template.rendered into template.event

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have this menu from jQuery, referenced by "template.rendered".  This is so "var meny = Meny.create({})" runs perfectly.  However, in my "template.events", I want it to close the menu and then scroll down which is not working at the moment.  I believe this is due to being in "template.rendered" and I am trying to change the Boolean which is in the "template.events".  Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set properties to the template instance in the rendered callback like this :

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered=function(){
  this.stuff=123;
};
```

And later retrieve them in events like this :

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "click .whatever":function(event,template){
    // prints 123
    console.log(template.stuff);
  }
});
```

If you need it in template helpers, this is the proper syntax :

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  stuff:function(){
    return Template.instance().stuff;
  }
});
```